# Play - Sharing objects among requests with no need for persistence

Tags: playframework

In my Play application, I need to share some objects in between several requests, but have no need for any type of long term persistence.  The objects are too big to be stuffed into a cookie.  I could serialize them to a relational database, but that seems to heavy for my needs: it would suffice to somehow say "Keep this object around for 10 minutes, make it accessible to all threads, then throw it out"

How can I do this?

Comment: That pretty much describes caching:  https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaCache

Comment: I looked at caching - I can't get an idea of how long an object is kept for.  How do I know it will be around for 10 minutes?

Comment: Using `Cache.set`, you can set the TTL to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play's cache API is more than enough for this. It uses EHCache (an in-memory cache) as it's default implementation.

Play Scala:

```
import play.api.cache.Cache

val hugeList: List[String] = ...

Cache.set("keyName", hugeList, 600) // Caches `hugeList` as "keyName" for 10 minutes (600 seconds)

Cache.getAs[List[String]]("keyName") // Returns `Option[List[String]]` with the value if "keyName" is cached, otherwise `None`.

Cache.remove("keyName") // Removes this key from the cache.
```

Play Java:

```
import play.cache.Cache;

Cache.set("keyName", hugeList, 600); // Works exactly the same as the scala version.

Cache.get("keyName");  // Returns the cached value or `null`.

Cache.remove("keyName");  // Same as scala version.
```

Also be sure to include `cache` within `libraryDependencies` in your `build.sbt` or `Build.scala`.

API Docs: [Scala](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.cache.Cache$), [Java](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/play/cache/Cache.html).

Answer (score 1):

Google Guava collections are good match for your requirements. You can create in memory cache with expiration. [Guava Explained](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) and example from the link:

```
LoadingCache<Key, Graph> graphs = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
   .maximumSize(1000)
   .expireAfterWrite(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
   .removalListener(MY_LISTENER)
   .build(
       new CacheLoader<Key, Graph>() {
         public Graph load(Key key) throws AnyException {
           return createExpensiveGraph(key);
         }
       });
```

Alternatively, you could implement the cache yourself with [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

Comment: Great answer! If I could accept two I would.  I accepted the first because it's built into Play, but this is clearly a powerful and simple approach too.